# Running C++ called from Java on a particular CPU core

Tags: multithreading, binding, java-native-interface, affinity, time.h

I need to get the hardware time from a single CPU - each time :

Here is the setup in which i am doing this :

I am using time.h to get nano-second ticks using C/C++ - but this C/C++ is being called from Java using JNI -

For consistency i require that I use the same CPU each time -

1) Can I achieve this from within the C/C++ ? (recall this will be a shared library)

2) If 1) is not possible what is the next best way ?

3) Any (simple) examples would be great

thanks,

Farrukh

Comment: In my experience, questions about binding threads to CPUs pretty much mean such binding is completely unnecessary.  If you know enough to know when you need to bind threads to specific CPUs, you already know enough to know *how* to do it.  Conversely, if you don't know how to bind threads to CPUs, you don't really know enough to know when it's needed.  And it's almost never needed.  What actual *problem* are you trying to solve?  [This seems like an XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If you really do need that much control, Java is a bad choice.